# How do I add the registration via Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want it to be like the one in the image below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the FirebaseUI documentation on [configuring providers](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#adding-providers):

> You can enable sign-in providers like Google Sign-In or Facebook Log In by calling the `setAvailableProviders` method:

> ```
> startActivityForResult(
>    AuthUI.getInstance()
>            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
>            .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.MicrosoftBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.YahooBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.AppleBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
>                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.AnonymousBuilder().build()))
>            .build(),
>    RC_SIGN_IN);
> ```

So you can just set the providers you want in this call.

If you need any further customization of the FirebaseUI Auth UI, check the documentation on [UI customization](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#ui-customization). If you need customization beyond that, you'll have to fork the Github repo and make the changes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your code